# Class documentation outside declaration

Tags: php, netbeans

Is it possible to document methods, properties etc. outside of class declaration ?

```
<?php

// lib/classa.php

class ClassA {
   public function __call($method, $args)
   {
     if ($method == 'testA')
       return $method;
     else if ($method == 'testB')
       return $method;
   }
}
```

As you can see above class has some undocumented functionality that IDE could not get any notice of.

```
<?php

// app/index.php

/**
 * @method string ClassA::testA()
 * @method string ClassA::testB()
 */

$classa = new ClassA();
classa->testA();
#       ^
#       |
#       \_____Code suggestions here
```

I wounder of any possibility to hint IDE about missing features. It could help me out with missing documentation in libraries or document classes that are generated by framework but still used in actual project.

Answer (score 0):

If you use phpdoc it's impossible. You should read about [docblock](http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/guides/docblocks.html). `@method` is used another way:

```
/**
 * @method string testA()
 * @method string testB()
*/
class ClassA {
   public function __call($method, $args)
   {
     if ($method == 'testA')
       return $method;
     else if ($method == 'testB')
       return $method;
   }
}
```

You have two options: extend library class and document own class, or better one: contribute in library development and document library.